# How to save and get path of image Cropped Android from sd card?

Tags: android, image, crop

i learning crop image tutorial from http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/ , but the result or after crop , Image not save in SD Card, how to fix it ?

this te code

```
 package net.londatiga.android;

import java.io.File;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final String [] items           = new String [] {"Take from camera", "Select from gallery"};                
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter    = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder     = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) { //pick from camera
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                       "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

                    try {
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else { //pick from file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();

                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }
        } );

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        Button button   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_crop);
        mImageView      = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                doCrop();

                break;

            case PICK_FROM_FILE: 
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

                doCrop();

                break;          

            case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:          
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {               
                    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }

                File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            

                if (f.exists()) f.delete();

                break;

        }
    }

    private void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) {            
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title    = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon     = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                        startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                    }
                });

                builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                } );

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you get cropped images bitmap in your onActivityResult. If you want to save on Sd card card, do it in CROP_FROM_CAMERA case, else you can directly use the bitmap.

```
case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:          
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {               
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
                try {
                   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                   photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                   out.flush();
                   out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            

            if (f.exists()) f.delete();

            break;
```

in above code photo variable has your bitmap. you can use it.
it will save the image in saved_images folder on your SD card.

Comment: thanks.. but can you complete code from **case** until **break** , please  ?

Comment: thanks, it's work.... must add it's in manifest

` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />`